# Free Tickets to Rio!

Tags: wordplay, sports

I got an email from one of my friends in Brazil today morning:

---

*"Free tickets to the Rio Olympics if you can solve all these! Good luck!!"*

### Clues:

1. > $\longleftarrow 8\;\bar{\uparrow} $
2. > $10 n=$
3. > $\text{log}_{\boxed{b}}a+\bigg\{x\in V\bigg| \;||x||<r^2\bigg\}$
4. > Darts, fencing, baseball, and skeet-shooting without golf, skateboarding and table tennis
5. > I, on a strange game
6. > Foul herb; no return
7. > Proportion led by acid dissociation constant
8. > Each stilt is broken
9. > $\begin{cases}y=x^{20x},\\
   > y=x^{16},\\
   > xy^2+x^2-2x=0, \\
   > x^2+y^2=1.\end{cases}$
10. > When you line up and quarrel continuously
11. > Hello, your majesty!
12. > $f(\infty)^t+\bigg\{x\in V\bigg| \;||x||<r^2\bigg\}$

### Grid:

[image]

---

I really have no idea what this is all about, except that I have a feeling these are all sports related. Can you help me out by solving these for me?

---

### Note:

1. The clues above are not necessarily standard cryptic-clues. For example, almost none of them includes definitions.
2. Exactly half of them are related to non-Rio sports.

Comment: Got my mind blown by 4!

Comment: one of the best puzzle ..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1

> **W**eightlifting - arrow pointing West + eight + a symbol for lifting

2

> T**e**nnis - ten + n + is

3

> Baseba**l**l - b is the base of the logarithm + the equation for a ball

4

> **C**hess - remove the letters of golf, skateboarding and tabletennis from the letters of darts, fencing, baseball and skeetshooting. The remaining letters can be rearranged to form the word chess.

5

> **O**ina - anagram of "I, on a", and surely in a way strange, as I've never heared about it

6

> Bad**m**inton - bad mint + 'no' reversed

7

> Karat**e** - Ka is the [acid dissociation constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant) + rate

8

> A**t**hletics - the clue is an anagram (Credit goes to @RosieF)

9

> Jud**o** - plot the equations to get the shapes of the letters

10

> **R**owing (Credit goes to @RosieF)

11

> H**i**king - Hi, king!

12

> F**o**otball - f + $\infty$ + t + the equation for a ball

The phrase is

> Welcome to Rio

Comment: I can see the phrase already from these letters. rot13(`jrypbzrgbevb`)

Comment: I'd have never come up with 5 without guessing the phrase and searching for sports starting with this letter... ;)

Comment: Common Chris waiting for final answer..

Comment: There you go! Credit for 8 and 10 goes to @RosieF!

Comment: @Christoph. What? you've never heard of Oina? Tsk Tsk... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oin%C4%83.  Just for the record....I'm from Romania :D

Answer (score 7):

8.

> A**t**hletics (the clue is an anagram)

10.

> **R**owing

4.

> **C**hess (remove the letters in the latter list from the letters in the former list)